# WPF: Databinding to parameterized properties

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding

Given this class/property, how would I write a WPF data binding expression to get `myToken.DataItem("Phone")`?

```
Class Token
    Public Property DataItem(ByVal name As String) As Object
        Get
            If m_DataPoints.ContainsKey(name) Then Return m_DataPoints(name) Else Return Nothing
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object)
            Dim oldValue = DataItem(name)
            If Object.Equals(oldValue, value) Then Return
            m_DataPoints(name) = value
            OnPropertyChanged("DataPoint")
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: •Indexers of a property can be specified within square brackets following the property name where the indexer is applied. For instance, the clause Path=ShoppingCart[0] sets the binding to the index that corresponds to how your property's internal indexing handles the literal string "0". Multiple indexers are also supported. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Binding's indexer syntax should work for you as long as your indexed property is declared as default:

```
Default Public Property DataItem(ByVal name As String) As Object
```

In this case you can use:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Token[Phone]}" />
```

or if your token is your DataContext just:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding [Phone]}" />
```

WPF's Binding syntax has no mechanism for accessing a non-default indexer.  If you cannot make your indexer default, you'll have to use a converter:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Token,ConverterParameter=Phone,Converter={x:Static my:DataItemAccessor.Instance}}" />
```

Where `DataItemAccessor` is a trivial class you write that implements IValueConverter and accessed DataItem.

Comment: "WPF's Binding syntax has no mechanism for accessing a non-default indexer." Again they treat VB as a second-class langauge. Oh well, I'm still early enough in the process that I can use a default indexer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe more a workaround than a solution, but let me share my
experience :
In vb i tried to define an indexed property :
`Public Property MyIndProp(index As integer) As integer`
but couldn't get it to work in a binding, even with a converter.

( without converter :   < Control  ... Property={Binding MyIndProp[0]} />

with converter    :
   < Control ...  Property={Binding MyIndProp[0], Converter={StaticResource MyPropIndexer}, Parameter=0} />  )

The 'solution' i found is to define the property as an array :

```
Public Property MyIndProp As integer()
```

and the binding works without converter.
(< Control  ... Property={Binding MyIndProp[0]} />  works fine)

Answer (score 0):

A binding cannot have a parameter.

I suggest writing a converter. A converter can have a parameter, which it can use to access the indexed property.

Another thing to try is to write an implementation of ICustomTypeDescriptor, where you return a subclass of PropertyDescriptor for each of the keys in the DataItem. This subclass will use DataItem to implement GetValue.

WPF will believe that you have a Phone property and will go through the PropertyDescriptor to get its value. The binding becomes simply: {Binding Path=Phone}.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you provide a property "Phone"?

Comment: Token is a generic object that holds basic information like CustomerKey, FirstName, and LastName. I'm looking for a place to shove additional information that comes back from queries without have to create countless subclasses.